# CryptoObfuscator + Android is missing a pdb file

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, obfuscation, crypto-obfuscator

I tried to use CryptoObfuscator to obfuscate my Android app, but it doesn't generate all the pdb files.

My Xamarin.Forms solution has 11 projects, 7 of them should be obfuscated. I disabled most CryptoObfuscator features just to test it. My .obproj file contains these settings for all dlls:

```
  <Assembly Load="true" Path=".\bin\Release\RoyalMobileApps.XF.dll" XapEntryName="" KeyFilePath="" KeyFileContainsPublicKeyOnly="False" CertFilePath="" TimeStampURL="" Rfc3161TimestampURL="False" SHA256SigningAlgorithm="False" Embed="True" AddExceptionReporting="False" PfxPassword="" PfxPasswordCert="" IsWinRTAssembly="False">
    <ObfuscationSettings EncryptStrings="True" EncryptMethods="False" EncryptConstants="False" SuppressReflector="False" ReduceMetaData="False" ObfuscationDisposition="1" FlowObfuscation="2" CodeMasking="0" SuppressILDASM="True" SuppressReflection="False" CombineResources="True" EncryptResources="True" CompressResources="True" MarkAsSealed="False" EnableTamperDetection="False" EnableAntiDebugging="False" SymbolRenaming="True" HideExternalCalls="False" HideInternalCalls="False" GeneratePdbFile="True" ObfuscatePdbFileNames="True" IncludeLocalVariablesInPdbFile="False" Encrypt="False" Compress="False" MSBuild="False" ObfuscatedNamespace="A" RetainNamespace="False" ModuleInitializationMethod="" LicensingMerge="False" RemoveConstants="False" ProcessSatelliteAssemblies="True">
      <Watermarks Watermark0="" Watermark1="" Watermark2="" Watermark3="" Watermark4="" Watermark5="" Watermark6="" Watermark7="" Watermark8="" Watermark9="" />
    </ObfuscationSettings>
  </Assembly>
```

As you can see I set GeneratePdbFile="True" for all 7 projects. I integrated co.exe in my build process and it claims to have run successfully. It generates 7 dlls but only 6 pdbs. The pdb file for my main PCL project which I pasted above is missing and therefore Xamarins linker fails and I cannot build an apk.

How can I get CryptoObfuscator to create all pdbs? Or can I generate the apk without them?

Unfortunately the CryptoObfuscator support did not respond to my emails and I couldn't find anybody else with a similar problem.

Comment: What is the use case? Is this going to be a final `Release` configuration `.apk`(Aka released externally)? If so, there's really no need to even generate the `pdb` symbols if you do not plan to attach a debugger.

Comment: @JonDouglas Yes, this is the Release build. I don't want to debug in this build. I don't need the pdb files, but as they are created by default, I thought that maybe Xamarin needs them to build the apk. The linker definitely crashes if the pdb does not match with the dll. If you can tell me how to build the apk without pdbs, I'd also be happy.

Comment: I believe you can simply remove the `<DebugType>` property from your `Release` configuration all together: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/build_process/#Build_Properties It may come back as a `false` value, but that should prevent those I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by disabling the Pdbs at all. I switched to release mode and opened up the properties of each project which should be obfuscated. In *Build* / *Advanced* you can set the *Debug Info* to *None*.
In Crypto Obfuscator I disabled *Output Settings* / *Generate New Pdb File For Assembly*.
Then nothing created Pdb files. I got warnings when building the solution, but they can be ignored.

This answer should actually be credited to @JonDouglas, but he wrote only a comment.

Unfortunately I had to disable *Rename Symbols* too. But this was the main reason why I wanted to use Crypto Obfuscator. Because I couldn't get the Name Protection in ConfuserEx running. So as it doesn't work in either tool and Crypto Obfuscators support still didn't answer my email I'm back to ConfuserEx. This is free and it cannot be deobfuscated with de4dot.